# javascript push function is not working as expected. I am trying to push data to array or list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can you explain why the code block 1 is not working and how is it that code block 2 works
I am trying to add the data of my placeholder to the data of my storage.

```
  const [placeholder, setPlaceholder] = useState([
    {
      id: 0,
      title: null,
      icon: null,
      UUID: null,
      Children: [],
      action: null,
    },
  ]);
```

code block 1

```
  const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@custom_layout');
  
  if (JSON.parse(jsonValue) != null) {
    JSON.parse(jsonValue).push(placeholder[0]);
    console.log(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
  }
```

code block 2

```
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@custom_layout');
    const myData = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
    if (JSON.parse(jsonValue) != null) {
      JSON.parse(jsonValue).push(placeholder[0]);
      console.log(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
    }
```

Comment: What is `AsyncStorage` and what does it return?

Comment: Its the device storage and it returns json object. It returns data like my placeholder expect the values of the property are not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
JSON.parse(jsonValue).push(placeholder[0]);
console.log(JSON.parse(jsonValue));
```

This likely does add add placeholder to the jsonValue, but it does not assign it or modify jsonValue.

Instead:

```
const output = JSON.parse(jsonValue).push(placeholder[0]);
console.log(output);
```

In steps:

```
const obj = JSON.parse(jsonValue);
obj.push(placeholder[0])
console.log(obj);
```

edit: if code block 2 does indeed work then this is not correct. I think it's more likely that code block 2 is console logging the assigned value `placeholder[0]`.

Comment: I don't think you answered the question.

Comment: The question is very likely based off OPs misunderstanding. I think my answer will help them understand where they're going wrong.

Comment: AsyncStorage returns the following
 [
    {
      id: 0,
      title: 'Booking 1',
      icon: 'book.png',
      UUID: 'abc123',
      Children: [],
      action: 'folder,
    },
  ]

Comment: I am trying to read the data from AsyncStorage then I am trying to push the placeholder into the list created by AsyncStorage before I set my state. again code block 2 works however code block 1 does not.